# Why deleting function gives error on linked-list in C

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, linked-list, structure

I am currently working on a program based on linked-list. But my delete function causes crashes on my program. I want to allow users to delete a flight by it's fligt number. But I don't know what causes crash. How to fix this? Thanks

```
struct flight {
    int number;
    char source[20];
    char destination[20]; 
    struct flight* next;
};

void enter();
void display();
void delete();
int count();

typedef struct flight NODE;

NODE* head_node, * first_node, * temp_node = 0, * prev_node, next_node;
int data;
char data2[20], data3[20];
```

```
void delete()
{
    temp_node = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    temp_node = first_node;
    int counter, flightno, j;
    temp_node->number = data;
    counter = count();
    printf("\nEnter flight number to delete: \n");
    scanf("%d", &flightno);

    for (j = 0; j <= counter; j++) 
    {
        if (flightno == data) {
            temp_node = temp_node->next;
            first_node = temp_node;
            printf("\nFlight log deleted.\n");
        }
        else 
        {
            printf("Flight number not found.");
        }
    }
}
int count()
{
    int count = 0;
    temp_node = first_node;
    while (temp_node != 0) {
        count++;
        temp_node = temp_node->next;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Do not make significant changes to your question once an answer has been posted. Such changes invalidates the already posted answers. Not good. What you can do is to edit the question and add a version 2 of your code below the first version.

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  first because it is missing the needed `#include` statements for the needed header files.  Are you expecting us to guess as to which header files your code actually includes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: **Avoid global variables!**

In your `delete` function you set the value of the global variable `temp_node`.

Then you call the function `count`. In `count` you also use the global variable `temp_node`. You change it until it has the value NULL.

Then back in the `delete` function, you do:

```
temp_node = temp_node->next;
```

Dereference of a NULL pointer! That is real bad and crashes your program.

So to start with: **Get rid of all global variables**

As an example, your `count` function should be:

```
int count(NODE* p)
{
    int count = 0;
    while (p != NULL) {
        count++;
        p = p->next;
    }
    return count;
}
```

and call it like: `counter = count(first_node);`

And your `delete` function could look like:

```
NODE* delete(NODE* first_node) { ... }
```

That said ...

The principle in your `delete` function is wrong. You don't need to count the number of nodes. Simply iterate until you reach the end, i.e. `next` is NULL.

Further - why do you `malloc` memory in the `delete` function? And why do you overwrite the pointer just after `malloc`? Then you have a memory leak.

```
temp_node = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));  // WHY??
temp_node = first_node;  // UPS... temp_node assigned new value.
                         // So malloc'ed memory is lost.
```

Now - what happens when you find the matching node:

```
    if (flightno == data) {
        temp_node = temp_node->next;
        first_node = temp_node;       // UPS.. first_node changed
        printf("\nFlight log deleted.\n");
    }
```

Then you change first_node. So all nodes **before** the current node is lost! That's not what you want. You only want to change `first_node` when the match is on the very first node in the linked list.

Then: `for (j = 0; j <= counter; j++)` --> `for (j = 0; j < counter; j++)` But as I said before... don't use this kind of loop.

Use something like:

```
while (temp_node != NULL) 
{
    ...
    temp_node = temp_node->next;
}
```

BTW: Why do you do a print out in every loop? Move the negative print out outside the loop.

A `delete` function can be implemented in many ways. The below example is not the most compact implementation but it's pretty simple to understand.

```
NODE* delete(NODE* head, int value_to_match)
{
    NODE* p = head;
    if (p == NULL) return NULL;

    // Check first node
    if (p->data == value_to_match)
    {
        // Delete first node
        head = head->next;   // Update head to point to next node
        free(p);             // Free (aka delete) the node
        return head;         // Return the new head
    }

    NODE* prev = p;          // prev is a pointer to the node before
    p = p->next;             // the node that p points to

    // Check remaining nodes
    while(p != NULL)
    {
        if (p->data == value_to_match)
        {
            prev->next = p->next; // Take the node that p points to out
                                  // of the list, i.e. make the node before
                                  // point to the node after
            free(p);              // Free (aka delete) the node
            return head;          // Return head (unchanged)
        }

        prev = p;                 // Move prev and p forward 
        p = p->next;              // in the list
    };

    return head;  // Return head (unchanged)
}
```

and call it like:

```
head = delete(head, SOME_VALUE);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably making an extra loop in your delete function. You should check if you are deleting an node which isn't part of your linked list.

Comment: any suggestion as example?

Comment: I can see that you are making loops from j=0 to j<=counter. Try making it j<counter and see if it works.

Comment: @R-Gate you would probably need to modify your delete function a bit. Take reference of any online sources where you will get delete_node function and match it according to your needs. If you still don't get it, feel free to comment